Can I say "keep your head tipping backwards for 2 minutes" to mean to keep the head still and in a state that it is fixed at a tipping position?
After I put in eye drops, I need to keep the head  still and in a state that it is fixed at a tipping position for 2 minutes so that more drops get into my eyes and don't come out too much.
The verb "tip" or "lean" are action verbs which means to move the head into a slanting position.
I am not sure if we have any adjectives deriving from the verb "tip" or "lean".
We have the adjective "still". I can just say "keep your head still" (keep something adjective). But it is partially correct as I need to let people know my head is still at a slanting position.
Or I can just say "tip your head far back and then keep it still in that position".
What about "keep your head tipping far back"? It sounds like the head keeps moving to the back repeatedly.

I would say "tipped".

And I would say "tilted".

It matches expressions like "Keep your mouth closed", "keep your knees bent", or "Keep your eyes peeled". In some cases "-ing" would be fine, but in others it isn't as good ("bending" can refer to maintaining a bend rather than moving, but "bent" is still commoner). It's easier to use the same structure in every case.

With instructions, it's always good to be as precise and explicit as possible, something like: "Tilt your head back as far as you can comfortably to be looking up at the ceiling, then maintain that position without moving your head for two minutes."

Keep your head tipped/tilted backwards for two minutes without moving.

We can form adjectives from both "tip" and "lean". Both verbs are correct here, and "tip" is probably preferred. The problem isn't your choice of verb, but your choice of participle.
"Keep your head tipping back" indicates a continuous action. I'm picturing someone's head tipping farther and farther back for 2 minutes like in a horror movie.
Past participial adjectives describe the state of something after the verb has has already happened, so that's what you want:

Keep your head tipped back."


+1 for the past participial form "tipped back".  We could also say "Keep tipping your head back" and "keep tipping" wouldn't mean farther and farther but merely to maintain that pose or posture.

Is there a regional element to this?  For example, there seem to be common US usages such as ‘heaping spoonful’ which sound just as wrong to these UK ears as ‘tipping’ does here.

@gidds, in that case, "heaping" is an adjective. I see nothing odd about "heaping spoonful", any more than "overflowing spoonful" or "glowing spoonful" (though I don't know why it would be glowing). That said, "heaped spoonful" would also be valid, though I don't think I've ever heard that.

@Matthew In the UK, we do indeed say "heaped spoonful" rather than "heaping spoonful". Collins also gives "heaped" in this context as "in British English" and "heaping" as "[US]".

@Matthew ‘overflowing’ would be different, because it's something done by the spoon('s contents); ‘heaping’, however, is something that you do when filling it.  By the time you hold it aloft, you have finished heaping it — it has been heaped.  So here in the UK, taking ‘a heaping spoonful’ sounds just as wrong as would taking ‘a packing lunch’ or a dish of ‘roasting beef’.

@gidds, I guess in the US we believe it's legitimate to apply the verb "heap" to a pile of stuff.  (Also, "roasting beef" sounds somewhat-okay, except I would understand it to mean "beef suitable for roasting". In the UK, do you not have "drinking water"?)

@Matthew Yes, ‘roasting beef’ could mean beef suitable for roasting (along the same lines as e.g. the more common ‘stewing steak’) — but I said ‘a dish of…’, and I'd hope that the roasting had been completed before it was served :-)

@gidds, right, I agree that "roasting beef" "roast[ed] beef" are not interchangeable. But a heap of (let's say) sugar is still forming that heap, so the present tense is suitable. ("Did you see that heaping pile of rocks?") That doesn't work with beef because beef doesn't roast itself. I've been served sizzling steak, however. (Some people also like theirs "mooing" or "bleeding".)

@Matthew, I'm chipping in as another UK speaker, and the "heaping pile of rocks" sounds as alien to me as "heaping spoonful" - I'd use "heaped" for both.  But there is a certain tower in Italy that I'd describe as "leaning", so we're at the usual level of consistency for the English language!
